# Animated transformations on SVG do not work in Firefox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, svg, transition, mask

In process of developing an animated spotlight using SVG paths I have met cross browser problem.
I have SVG path with one shape that is covering whole page and semitransparent and another shape that masks it using "evenodd" attribute.
Then using jQuery I'm changing paths coordinates and the so called spotlight effect work. The spotlight is animated because I have added transition style for all paths and all is working on Chrome but not Firefox and IE.
In Firefox and IE it performs without slight animation but just jumps to new position.

Does anyone met this kind of problem? And are the a solution of workaround to get this kind of spotlight work?

Plz click on buttons to get shapes changed.

```js
$("#mod").click(function() {
  $(".cls-1").attr("d", "M0,0 V1000 H1600 V0 M100,100 h200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z");
})

$("#cir").click(function() {
  $(".cls-1").attr("d", "M0,0 V1000 H1600 V0 M400,100 h100 a200,200 0 0 1 200,200 v0 a200,200 0 0 1 -200,200 h0 a200,200 0 0 1 -200,-200 v0 a200,200 0 0 1 200,-200 z");
})

$("#tomenu").click(function() {
  $(".cls-1").attr("d", "M0,0 V1000 H1600 V0 M"+$(".menu").position().left+","+$(".menu").position().top+" h"+$(".menu").width()+" a0,0 0 0 1 0,0 v"+$(".menu").height()+" a0,0 0 0 1 0,0 h-"+$(".menu").width()+" a0,0 0 0 1 0,0 v-"+$(".menu").height()+" a0,0 0 0 1 0,0 z");
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #FFFFFF url(http://vahramtorosyan.com/reps/pexels-photo-356056.jpeg) no-repeat;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-size: cover
}

path, circle, line {
      transition: all 1s;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s;
     -moz-transition: all 1s;
     -o-transition: all 1s;
}


.menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1500px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9001;
}

.block {
  width: 220px;
  height: 1500px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
}

.maindiv {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div style="maindiv">
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1600 1000">       <defs>
  <style>.cls-1{fill:#0c78bf; fill-opacity: .8}</style>
  </defs>
  <title>Testing SVG</title>
  <path class="cls-1" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0,0 V1000 H1600 V0 M100,100 h200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z"/>  
</svg>  
</div>

<button id="mod" style="z-index: 9999; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 25px;">SHAPE 1</button>

<button id="cir" style="z-index: 9999; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 110px;">SHAPE 2</button>

<button id="tomenu" style="z-index: 9999; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 195px;">SHAPE 3</button>
```

Comment: paths co-ordinates in Firefox (and IE) are not CSS styles they are attributes. Attributes are not subject to CSS transitions. You could reengineer your solution to us SMIL (for IE you'd need to use fakeSmile as it doesn't support SMIL natively).